# Why does entering { foo: 'value' }.foo in the console throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, console, javascript-objects

When creating an object containing a key value pair, binding that to a variable and then accessing that property, it works fine:

```
var b = { foo: 'value' };
b.foo;
// "value"
```

If I create a similar object, directly access its property and bind that to a variable, it works as well:

```
var b = { foo: 'value' }.foo;
b;
// "value"
```

However, when submitting the following code to the console, this results in an error:

```
{ foo: 'value' }.foo;
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Why?

Comment: Because `{` at the beginning of the line (the beginning of a statement really) denotes the beginning of a block, not an object literal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: Also, `({ foo: 'value' }).foo` will work fine.